# Socket.io connection from Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova, socket.io

I am trying to connect to socket.io server from my PhoneGap Application like below.
First I have added this line to android config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Then I have saved socket.io client JS file to my PhoneGap resource folder(As I do not want to load JS file from server again and again for each startup) and added to index.html

```
<script src="js/socket.io" />

Then my code goes like below  

 var socket = io.connect('http://n.n.n.n:3000/'); // n.n.n.n is my IP address
 socket.on('connect', function() {
     alert('check 2', socket.socket.connected);
 });
```

But this is not working. Is anything missing or I am doing it in wrong approach ?

If I include from host like this from host

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ip:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Now the connectivity is working fine. But the problem is everytime when I open the app it will be loaded again and connectivity will happen again. And it will not receive when app is running in background.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to comunicate with your server without loading the socket-client form the server. The comunication happens coz you are loading the js from server. There's no other way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, it is possible but you have to configure at node js side to allow cross origin headers. And its working for me too

Comment: Well, sorry for the mistake then, can you explain how do you do that?
I'm interested to do something like that, as far as i knew you should load the js from the server and it will be nice to know the way it works. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please check this https://bitbucket.org/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket-demo/src/e6a874f8280900c0273af552c4970232d27c38b5/client/www/js/socket.io.js?at=master